# Data too long for column error occurs (mysql)

Tags: mysql, jpa

When insert 8 English characters into a varchar(8) column, Data too long for column error occurs.
I use JPA and I've tried changing sql_mode, but it's the same.
Even when I debugged it, there was no error when inserting, but an sql error occurred when the method containing the insert ended, so I don't know what the problem is. ㅜㅜ

```
try {
    Service service = helper.createService(params);
    return new RestResponse(service.getId());
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    throw new ResourceDuplicatedException();
}
```

There is no error until "createService" is finished.
Even if I debug the next line, it doesn't go through and I get an sql exception.

service.java

```
@column(length = 8, nullable = flase)
private String code;
```

Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bm_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_owner` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `grade` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade_filename` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `infra_operator` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `operation_switch_status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_developer` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_operator` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `standard_code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `business_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `reserved1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reserved2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `em_zone_code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `unit_code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mdm_syncable` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `is_test` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_contact` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mdm_synced` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updator` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_mdm_sync` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mdm_closing_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `it_cont_no` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `it_infra_impl_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` tinyblob,
  `comp_gubun` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK7643C6B5A6FE833D` (`business_id`),
  KEY `idx_service_code` (`code`),
  KEY `UK_c1w41qunhfmcu9ggbkd0p67v0` (`name`,`created`),
  KEY `UK_4pb17og0koa3urm5auxptl4yo` (`status`,`name`,`created`),
  KEY `FK_l6u6vmgeo9pkekbxi4g0j88e8` (`bm_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7643C6B5A6FE833D` FOREIGN KEY (`business_id`) REFERENCES `business` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_l6u6vmgeo9pkekbxi4g0j88e8` FOREIGN KEY (`bm_code`) REFERENCES `bm_codes` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2341 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

ERROR

```
13:58:27.700 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR [o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] Data truncation: Data too long for column 'code' at row 1
```

Code

```
@Transactional(JpaConfig.TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
public Service createService(Long businessId, String name, String username,
        String description, String code, Long bmCodeId, 
        ProviderType providerType, EmZoneCode zoneCode,
        boolean isTest, boolean isMdmSyncable, String itInfraImplId, String itContNo, String compGubun) {

    Service service = serviceService.createService(
            bizManager.getBusiness(businessId),
            name,
            code,
            description,
            bmCodeId,
            providerType,
            zoneCode, 
            isTest, 
            isMdmSyncable,
            itInfraImplId,
            itContNo, 
            compGubun);
    memberService.addUser(service, username, ServiceRole.PLANNER);
    return service;
}

@Override
@Transactional(JpaConfig.TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
public Service createService(Business business, String name, String code,
        String description, Long bmCodeId, ProviderType providerType,
        EmZoneCode emZoneCode, boolean isTest, boolean isMdmSync, String itInfraImplId, String itContNo, String compGubun) {
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        throw new InvalidRequestValueException("Service name is empty");
    }
    Service service = Service.create(business, name);
    service.setProviderType(providerType);
    service.setTest(isTest);
    service.setMdmSyncable(isMdmSync);
    service.setDescription(description);
    service.setItInfraImplId(itInfraImplId);
    service.setItContNo(itContNo);
    service.setCompGubun(compGubun);
    setServiceNameCode(service, code);

    if (bmCodeId != null) {
        BmCode bmCode = bmCodeService.get(bmCodeId);
        service.setBmCode(bmCode);
    }

    if (providerType == ProviderType.EM12C) {
        service.setEmZoneCode(emZoneCode);
    }
    
    return serviceRepository.save(service);
}
```

[image: DEBUG]

[image: DEBUG]

[image: DEBUG]

Comment: Please share the log with the exception and table DDL as well.

Comment: Show us the code doing the insert.  What string was it trying to insert?

Comment: It seems you are trying to save a Chinese name. Does your DB & Table support `utf8mb4` Character Set? And especially that column is set to Collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`?  Some character sets and collations may not support those characters. And trying to save 3 Chinese characters may actually be tried to save as 9 ASCII characters and that may result in more than 8 length and fail.

Comment: This is korean and I tried english also. It is not problem.

Comment: It seems the error is raised for code, where it is just `qwerqwer` - 8 chars. That should fit fine in `varchar(8)`

Comment: Not related to the solution, but still. In your table design, last line, it is `) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2341 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`.  `utf8` is not good. Better use `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. `utf8` uses max 3-bytes, while `utf8mb4` uses max 4 bytes, and covers a wider character range.

Comment: Your screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYy7U.png - shows it raises a duplicate name error, while you have stated that you are facing `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'code' at row 1`. So, screenshots and data showing up in them seem to be for a different case.

Comment: @SoonHo Before inserting data into the VARCHAR(8) column, ensure that the data you're inserting does not have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: At least in the screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/769rw.png - on the right side expressions window, `code` has value `qwerqwer` without any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: `'qwerqwer'` will insert into a varchar(8) column, but 8 Korean characters will not, see https://dbfiddle.uk/VzSeICrJ  - this issue isn't reproducible for `'qwerqwer'`

Comment: Like other said, this is definitely an encoding issue. Check that your database uses the correct encoding; then check that your client connects using the right encoding as well. You have to make sure the whole data flux is coherent back-and-forth.

Comment: Is `ㅜㅜ` Korean characters in the column?  It is only 2 character / 6 bytes.

Comment: @Ishan - `VARCHAR(8)` allows 8 _characters_ in any language, even though it may take 24 bytes for Korean, or even up to 32 bytes for some Chinese characters.

Comment: "qwerqwer" is _after_ truncation -- what was the string _before_?

Comment: @RickJames, Yes, I am aware that VARCHAR(8) will support 8 characters of any language. But, the concern is the character set and collation. I am just saying to use `utf8mb4` as charset and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as the collation to support the widest range of characters. MySQL's `utf8` is actually NOT the standard `utf8`, it just supports 1-3 bytes. But `utf8mb4` supports 1-4 bytes. If proper charset & collation is not used, then characters that need more bytes may have issues in storing, even if those are <= 8 characters.

Comment: Yes the character set utf8mb4, _with any matching collation_, handles the widest set of characters.  Technically, UTF-8 can handle more than 4 bytes, but I doubt if I will see than in my lifetime; there is still a lot of room in 4 bytes.